# openssl_csr_sign return false cannot get certificate

Tags: php, openssl, certificate, sign

So, I try to make my own CA (Certificate Authority) using PHP and Openssl. I try to create user CSR and sign them.

```
function addcsr(){
    $dn = array(
        "countryName" => $_POST['CountryName'],
        "stateOrProvinceName" => $_POST['StateOrProvince'],
        "localityName" => $_POST['LocalityName'],
        "organizationName" => $_POST['OrganizationalName'],
        "organizationalUnitName" => $_POST['OrganizationalUnitName'],
        "commonName" => $_POST['CommonName'],
        "emailAddress" => $_POST['EmailAddress']
    );

    $configArgs = array(
        'private_key_bits' => 2048
    );
    $key = openssl_pkey_new($configArgs);

    openssl_pkey_export($key, $privkey);

    $pubkey = openssl_pkey_get_details($key);
    $pubkey = $pubkey["key"];

    $csr = openssl_csr_new($dn, $privkey);
    openssl_csr_export($csr, $csrstring);

    $cacert = "file://ca.pem";
    $privkeyca = array("file://ca.key", "daniel123");

    $usercert = openssl_csr_sign($csrstring, $cacert, $privkeyca, 365);

    // test
    $this->load->view('create_view', $data);
```

Everyting works really fine until the openssl_csr_sign($csrstring, $cacert, $privkeyca, 365).
$usercert return false and there is an error:

> Message: openssl_csr_sign() [function.openssl-csr-sign]: cannot get cert from parameter 2

I've tried to change:

> authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always,issuer:always
>   into
>   authorityKeyIdentifier=issuer:always
>   Not good, still the same error.

I've also try every possibilities with the $cacert and $privkeyca, still error :(

Or maybe I have to change something in my openssl.cnf file?
Here is my openssl.cnf file (I just copy & paste it):

```
#
# OpenSSL example configuration file.
# This is mostly being used for generation of certificate requests.
#

# This definition stops the following lines choking if HOME isn't
# defined.
HOME            = .
RANDFILE        = $ENV::HOME/.rnd

# Extra OBJECT IDENTIFIER info:
#oid_file       = $ENV::HOME/.oid
oid_section     = new_oids

# To use this configuration file with the "-extfile" option of the
# "openssl x509" utility, name here the section containing the
# X.509v3 extensions to use:
# extensions        = 
# (Alternatively, use a configuration file that has only
# X.509v3 extensions in its main [= default] section.)

[ new_oids ]

# We can add new OIDs in here for use by 'ca' and 'req'.
# Add a simple OID like this:
# testoid1=1.2.3.4
# Or use config file substitution like this:
# testoid2=${testoid1}.5.6

####################################################################
[ ca ]
default_ca  = CA_default        # The default ca section

####################################################################
[ CA_default ]

dir                 = ./demoCA                  # Where everything is kept
certs               = $dir/certs                # Where the issued certs are kept
crl_dir             = $dir/crl                  # Where the issued crl are kept
database            = $dir/index.txt            # database index file.
#unique_subject     = no                        # Set to 'no' to allow creation of
                                                # several ctificates with same subject.
new_certs_dir       = $dir/newcerts             # default place for new certs.

certificate         = $dir/cacert.pem           # The CA certificate
serial              = $dir/serial               # The current serial number
crlnumber           = $dir/crlnumber            # the current crl number
                                                # must be commented out to leave a V1 CRL
crl                 = $dir/crl.pem              # The current CRL
private_key         = $dir/private/cakey.pem    # The private key
RANDFILE            = $dir/private/.rand        # private random number file

x509_extensions     = usr_cert                  # The extentions to add to the cert

# Comment out the following two lines for the "traditional"
# (and highly broken) format.
name_opt            = ca_default                # Subject Name options
cert_opt            = ca_default                # Certificate field options

# Extension copying option: use with caution.
# copy_extensions   = copy

# Extensions to add to a CRL. Note: Netscape communicator chokes on V2 CRLs
# so this is commented out by default to leave a V1 CRL.
# crlnumber must also be commented out to leave a V1 CRL.
# crl_extensions    = crl_ext

default_days        = 365                       # how long to certify for
default_crl_days= 30                            # how long before next CRL
default_md  = sha1                              # which md to use.
preserve    = no                                # keep passed DN ordering

# A few difference way of specifying how similar the request should look
# For type CA, the listed attributes must be the same, and the optional
# and supplied fields are just that :-)
policy      = policy_match

# For the CA policy
[ policy_match ]
countryName     = match
stateOrProvinceName = match
organizationName    = match
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName      = supplied
emailAddress        = optional

# For the 'anything' policy
# At this point in time, you must list all acceptable 'object'
# types.
[ policy_anything ]
countryName     = optional
stateOrProvinceName = optional
localityName        = optional
organizationName    = optional
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName      = supplied
emailAddress        = optional

####################################################################
[ req ]
default_bits        = 2048
default_keyfile     = privkey.pem
distinguished_name  = req_distinguished_name
attributes      = req_attributes
x509_extensions = v3_ca # The extentions to add to the self signed cert

# Passwords for private keys if not present they will be prompted for
# input_password = secret
# output_password = secret

# This sets a mask for permitted string types. There are several options. 
# default: PrintableString, T61String, BMPString.
# pkix   : PrintableString, BMPString.
# utf8only: only UTF8Strings.
# nombstr : PrintableString, T61String (no BMPStrings or UTF8Strings).
# MASK:XXXX a literal mask value.
# WARNING: current versions of Netscape crash on BMPStrings or UTF8Strings
# so use this option with caution!
string_mask = nombstr

# req_extensions = v3_req # The extensions to add to a certificate request

[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName         = Country Name (2 letter code)
countryName_default     = AU
countryName_min         = 2
countryName_max         = 2

stateOrProvinceName     = State or Province Name (full name)
stateOrProvinceName_default = Some-State

localityName            = Locality Name (eg, city)

0.organizationName      = Organization Name (eg, company)
0.organizationName_default  = Internet Widgits Pty Ltd

# we can do this but it is not needed normally :-)
#1.organizationName     = Second Organization Name (eg, company)
#1.organizationName_default = World Wide Web Pty Ltd

organizationalUnitName      = Organizational Unit Name (eg, section)
#organizationalUnitName_default =

commonName          = Common Name (eg, YOUR name)
commonName_max          = 64

emailAddress            = Email Address
emailAddress_max        = 64

# SET-ex3           = SET extension number 3

[ req_attributes ]
challengePassword       = A challenge password
challengePassword_min       = 4
challengePassword_max       = 20

unstructuredName        = An optional company name

[ usr_cert ]

# These extensions are added when 'ca' signs a request.

# This goes against PKIX guidelines but some CAs do it and some software
# requires this to avoid interpreting an end user certificate as a CA.

basicConstraints=CA:FALSE

# Here are some examples of the usage of nsCertType. If it is omitted
# the certificate can be used for anything *except* object signing.

# This is OK for an SSL server.
# nsCertType            = server

# For an object signing certificate this would be used.
# nsCertType = objsign

# For normal client use this is typical
# nsCertType = client, email

# and for everything including object signing:
# nsCertType = client, email, objsign

# This is typical in keyUsage for a client certificate.
# keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment

# This will be displayed in Netscape's comment listbox.
nsComment           = "OpenSSL Generated Certificate"

# PKIX recommendations harmless if included in all certificates.
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer

# This stuff is for subjectAltName and issuerAltname.
# Import the email address.
# subjectAltName=email:copy
# An alternative to produce certificates that aren't
# deprecated according to PKIX.
# subjectAltName=email:move

# Copy subject details
# issuerAltName=issuer:copy

#nsCaRevocationUrl      = http://www.domain.dom/ca-crl.pem
#nsBaseUrl
#nsRevocationUrl
#nsRenewalUrl
#nsCaPolicyUrl
#nsSslServerName

[ v3_req ]

# Extensions to add to a certificate request

basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment

[ v3_ca ]


# Extensions for a typical CA


# PKIX recommendation.

subjectKeyIdentifier=hash

authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always,issuer:always

# This is what PKIX recommends but some broken software chokes on critical
# extensions.
#basicConstraints = critical,CA:true
# So we do this instead.
basicConstraints = CA:true

# Key usage: this is typical for a CA certificate. However since it will
# prevent it being used as an test self-signed certificate it is best
# left out by default.
# keyUsage = cRLSign, keyCertSign

# Some might want this also
# nsCertType = sslCA, emailCA

# Include email address in subject alt name: another PKIX recommendation
# subjectAltName=email:copy
# Copy issuer details
# issuerAltName=issuer:copy

# DER hex encoding of an extension: beware experts only!
# obj=DER:02:03
# Where 'obj' is a standard or added object
# You can even override a supported extension:
# basicConstraints= critical, DER:30:03:01:01:FF

[ crl_ext ]

# CRL extensions.
# Only issuerAltName and authorityKeyIdentifier make any sense in a CRL.

# issuerAltName=issuer:copy
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always,issuer:always

[ proxy_cert_ext ]
# These extensions should be added when creating a proxy certificate

# This goes against PKIX guidelines but some CAs do it and some software
# requires this to avoid interpreting an end user certificate as a CA.

basicConstraints=CA:FALSE

# Here are some examples of the usage of nsCertType. If it is omitted
# the certificate can be used for anything *except* object signing.

# This is OK for an SSL server.
# nsCertType            = server

# For an object signing certificate this would be used.
# nsCertType = objsign

# For normal client use this is typical
# nsCertType = client, email

# and for everything including object signing:
# nsCertType = client, email, objsign

# This is typical in keyUsage for a client certificate.
# keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment

# This will be displayed in Netscape's comment listbox.
nsComment           = "OpenSSL Generated Certificate"

# PKIX recommendations harmless if included in all certificates.
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer:always

# This stuff is for subjectAltName and issuerAltname.
# Import the email address.
# subjectAltName=email:copy
# An alternative to produce certificates that aren't
# deprecated according to PKIX.
# subjectAltName=email:move

# Copy subject details
# issuerAltName=issuer:copy

#nsCaRevocationUrl      = http://www.domain.dom/ca-crl.pem
#nsBaseUrl
#nsRevocationUrl
#nsRenewalUrl
#nsCaPolicyUrl
#nsSslServerName

# This really needs to be in place for it to be a proxy certificate.
proxyCertInfo=critical,language:id-ppl-anyLanguage,pathlen:3,policy:foo
```

Comment: Two thoughts: You're using a PEM and not a CRT, have you double checked PHP will work with this properly (it might do, I don't know)? What happens if you remove `file://`, or replace it with the absolute path, ie `file:///path/to/ca.pem`?

Comment: are you running this code locally? or in a remote server?

Comment: I've using .pem, .cer, and .crt, nothing works....

Comment: and the file:/// not work either....

Answer (score 7):

This is a common misunderstanding: `file://` stands for resource or file content. The easiest way to get rid of the error message `openssl_csr_sign() [function.openssl-csr-sign]: cannot get cert from parameter 2`(which means that path to file with certificate is not good enough for `openssl_csr_sign(args)`) therefore is:

```
$cacert = file_get_contents("/path_to_file/ca.pem");
$privkeyca = array(file_get_contents("/path_to_file/ca.key"), "daniel123");
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. It has solved the same issue that the OP had asked - using `file_get_contents()` to get the cert contents. Upvoted.